# getElementsByTagName is not a function. It called not on list

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="menuItems">
            <a href="#"><img src="package.svg" alt="Склад"><span> Склад<span></a>         
            <a href="#"><img src="report.svg" alt="Склад"><span> Отчеты</span></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="worker.svg" alt="Склад"><span> Персонал</span></a>
</div>


var menuText = document.getElementById("menuItems").getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i in menuText){
        var element = menuText[i];
        var text = element.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
       text.style.display = isMenuShort ? "none" : "inline";
    }
```

element is not a list. What I'm doing wrong? [image]

And my post

Comment: also close your span tags properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `for-loop` instead of [**`for-in`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate `array` or array-like collection.

`for-in` loop iterates enumerable-properties which are -

- 0
- 1
- 2
- length
- item
- namedItem

Hence loop is being iterated `6` times and `getElementsByTagName` of `menuText` other than `0, 1, 2` is `undefined`.

Also refer [***"Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?"***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

```js
var menuText = document.getElementById("menuItems").getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < menuText.length; i++) {
  var element = menuText[i];
  var text = element.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
  console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<div id="menuItems">
  <a href="#"><img src="package.svg" alt="Склад"><span> Склад</span></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="report.svg" alt="Склад"><span> Отчеты</span></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="worker.svg" alt="Склад"><span> Персонал</span></a>
</div>
```